# Asp.Net Mvc Delete file issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an issue with Files.

I am doing an image importer so clients put their files on an FTP server and then they can import it in the application.

During the import process I copy the file in the FTP Folder to another folder with File.copy

```
public List<Visuel> ImportVisuel(int galerieId, string[] images)
    {

        Galerie targetGalerie = MemoryCache.GetGaleriById(galerieId);
        List<FormatImage> listeFormats = MemoryCache.FormatImageToList();
        int i = 0;

        List<Visuel> visuelAddList = new List<Visuel>();
        List<Visuel> visuelUpdateList = new List<Visuel>();
        List<Visuel> returnList = new List<Visuel>();
        foreach (string item in images)
        {
            i++;
            Progress.ImportProgress[Progress.Guid] = "Image " + i + " sur " + images.Count() + " importées";
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(item);
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(item);
            string originalPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Uploads\\";
            string destinationPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/Catalogue") + "\\";
            Visuel importImage = MemoryCache.GetVisuelByFilName(fileName);
            bool update = true;
            if (importImage == null) { importImage = new Visuel(); update = false; }

            Size imageSize = importImage.GetJpegImageSize(originalPath + fileName);
            FormatImage format = listeFormats.Where(f => f.width == imageSize.Width && f.height == imageSize.Height).FirstOrDefault();
            string saveFileName = Guid.NewGuid() + extension;


            File.Copy(originalPath + fileName, destinationPath + saveFileName);


            if (format != null)
            {
                importImage.format = format;
                switch (format.key)
                {
                    case "Catalogue":
                        importImage.fileName = saveFileName;
                        importImage.originalFileName = fileName;
                        importImage.dossier = targetGalerie;
                        importImage.dossier_id = targetGalerie.id;
                        importImage.filePath = "Images/Catalogue/";
                        importImage.largeur = imageSize.Width;
                        importImage.hauteur = imageSize.Height;
                        importImage.isRoot = true;
                        if (update == false) { MemoryCache.Add(ref importImage); returnList.Add(importImage); }
                        if (update == true) visuelUpdateList.Add(importImage);
                        foreach (FormatImage f in listeFormats)
                        {
                            if (f.key.StartsWith("Catalogue_"))
                            {
                                string[] keys = f.key.Split('_');
                                string destinationFileName = saveFileName.Insert(saveFileName.IndexOf('.'), "-" + keys[1].ToString());
                                string destinationFileNameDeclinaison = destinationPath + destinationFileName;
                                VisuelResizer declinaison = new VisuelResizer();
                                declinaison.Save(originalPath + fileName, f.width, f.height, 1000, destinationFileNameDeclinaison);

                                Visuel visuel = MemoryCache.GetVisuelByFilName(fileName.Insert(fileName.IndexOf('.'), "-" + keys[1].ToString()));
                                update = true;
                                if (visuel == null) { visuel = new Visuel(); update = false; }

                                visuel.parent = importImage;

                                visuel.filePath = "Images/Catalogue/";
                                visuel.fileName = destinationFileName;
                                visuel.originalFileName = string.Empty;
                                visuel.format = f;
                                //visuel.dossier = targetGalerie; On s'en fout pour les déclinaisons
                                visuel.largeur = f.width;
                                visuel.hauteur = f.height;
                                if (update == false)
                                {
                                    visuelAddList.Add(visuel);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    visuelUpdateList.Add(visuel);
                                }
                                //importImage.declinaisons.Add(visuel);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
        MemoryCache.Add(ref visuelAddList);

        // FONCTION à implémenter
        MemoryCache.Update(ref visuelUpdateList);
        return returnList;
    }
```

After some processes on the copy (the original file is no more used)
the client have a pop-up asking him if he wants to delete the original files in the ftp folder.

If he clicks on Ok another method is called on the same controller 
and this method use

```
public void DeleteImageFile(string[] files)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            File.Delete(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + files[i].Replace(@"/", @"\"));
        }
    }
```

This method works fine and really delete the good files when I use it in other context.

But here I have an error message:

Process can't acces to file ... because it's used by another process.

Someone have an idea?

Thank you.

Here's the screenshot of Process Explorer

[image]

Comment: when do you get this error ? after deleting the file?

Comment: When I want to delete it the error occurs when I call the delete command

Comment: Did you close the File correctly beforehand?

Comment: How do you do that? 
I didn't see something like a Close method in the File class

Comment: you have to kill the process that is handling the file before you delete it, the easy way is to keep trying to delete it using thread.sleep or mark files to be deleted in a DB table and delete them at a later time

Comment: I tried Thread Sleep but it doesn't work, and If a user wants to delete a file, the file must be deleted with an acceptable delay eg. some miliseconds no more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

in my import method, there a call to that method

```
public void Save(string originalFile, int maxWidth, int maxHeight, int quality, string filePath)
        {
            Bitmap image = new Bitmap(originalFile);
            Save(ref image, maxWidth, maxHeight, quality, filePath);
        }
```

The bitmap maintains the file opened blocking delete.

just added

```
image.Dispose();
```

in the methos and it work fine.

Thank you for your help, and thank you for process explorer. Very useful tool

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of thing you can do here.

1) If you can repro it, you can use Process Explorer at that moment and see which process is locking the file and if the process is ur process then making sure that you close the file handle after your work is done.

2) Use `try/catch` around the delete statement and retry after few seconds to see if the file handle was released.

3) If you can do it offline you can put in some queue and do the deletion on it later on.

Comment: I can't do it offline. It's a web app.
try catch doesn't work either. the catch is called in loop.

How do you clos the file handle?
I use the File class and I didn"t see anything for that.

Thanks

Comment: When you get exception, add that in an array , and then retry after sometime.

Comment: @Julien can you show the code. That will make it much easier to help.

Comment: I added the two full methods in the question.
These two methods are in a disposable class called in a using statement from a controller. So the class is disposed between the two method calls

Comment: @Julien you got to find which process is holding the file handle using Process Explorer.

Comment: I got Process explorer, but I don't understand how to see wich process is blocking the file access

Comment: http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-find-out-which-windows-process-using-file.htm

Comment: I've put a screenshot of process explorer in the question

Answer (score 0):

You solve this by using c# locks. Just embed your code inside a lock statement and your threads will be safe and wait each other to complete processing.